# Laravel 5.2 Dingo API returning no records

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I was wondering if someone could give me a bit of guidance.

Im following a tutorial on building an API with Laravel which is found here

```
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-api-only-jwt-powered-laravel-app/
```

which is working well, but the problem im having is error responses and best practices.

If there are records in the DB then a simple

```
return $records;
```

works great, but what about when there are no records found?

In the tutorial, when no records are found it throws a http exception

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException;
```

but this returns a 404, which im not sure is relevant for no records in a DB, a 404 is more a page not found sort of thing isnt it?

So, i guess what im asking is, what is the best practice for returning a no records found in an API?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle it depending on the type of resource that is requested.

### Single Resource

When the requested resource is a single record, like for example `/api/v1/posts/1`, and there is no record with that id (1 in the example), you should return a `404 Not Found`. The requested location does not exist.

### Resource Collection

When the requested resource is a collection of records, for example 'all posts' (`/api/v1/posts`) and there are no records for that type of resource, you return a `200 OK` with an empty collection in the body. The requested location does exist, so it would be inappropriate to respond with a 404 here.

A JSON response body to a request for a collection with no records could for example look like so:

```
{
    "posts": []
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your response :)